# Formação de adjectivos gentílicos terminados em -istão?

Tags: morfologia, gentílicos, derivação

Tenho dúvidas sobre a formação de alguns adjectivos gentílicos partindo dos toponímios. O caso que quero perguntar é sobre os países terminados em **-istão**.

Vou começar por um exemplo simples, se usarmos o sufixo derivacional **-an-** (que forma adjectivos denominais) e o aplicarmos ao radical toponímio **Angol** obtemos os adjectivos gentílicos:

> Angol,a > Angol-an-o ou Angol-an-a

O próximo exemplo é mais complicado, se tentarmos o mesmo método com **Argélia** não é possivel porque não existe um sufixo **-n-** para formar o adjectivo directamente do possivel radical:

> Argéli,a > Argeli-n-o ou Argeli-n-a

Isto leva-me a pensar que no caso da **Argélia** o toponímio é já um derivado denominal do nome da capital [**Argel**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argel), portanto o sufixo denominal usado para formar o adjectivo seria **-in-** (este existe, é usado em pombal-**in**-o ou londr-**in**-o):

> Argel > Argel-in-o ou Argeli-n-a

Mas para casos como Afganistão ou Cazaquistão não sei qual é a regra a aplicar.
Poderá ser: **Afgan-ist-ão** e **Cazaqu-ist-ão**?

Em que a ordem de derivação é aplicar o sufixo adjectivalizador denominal **-ist-** seguido de um **-ão-**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso dos países com nome terminado em "-istão", o nome do país é que é derivado do gentílico e o sufixo [significa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uzbequist%C3%A3o#Etimologia) "terra de", de forma que, e.g., "Afeganistão" significa "Terra dos afegãos".

A Wikipedia (original em inglês, tradução livre) [esclarece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-stan):

> -stan (Persa: ـستان; stân [após vogal], estân ou istân [após consoante]) tem o significado de "lugar rico em" [...] é amplamente usado em línguas asiáticas influenciadas pelo persa [...] é análogo ao sufixo germânico "*land*" ["terra"]

Ou seja, o sufixo não é -ist + -ão, mas -istão mesmo.